# How does the following JavaScript syntax work? array['push']('5')

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

While reverse-engineering some obfuscated JavaScript code for a CTF, I came across the following syntax:

`array['push']('5');`

It pushes '5' at the end of the array, which seems logical, but I just do not understand why this syntax works, since I haven't managed to find anything about it (not on the [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array), not on the [W3C website](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp), and the latest [ECMAScript specification](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/) is a bit too dense for me to understand).

I'm thinking it has something to do with arrays being a special case of objects, but I'm not versed enough in JavaScript to figure it out.

Comment: `array['push']` means exactly the same thing as `array.push`. It has nothing to do with arrays being special. That's the normal and universal way that object property access works in JavaScript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In JavaScript, you can access object properties either using dot notation or square brackets. So `object.propertyname` is equivalent to `object['propertyname']`. Normally we use square brackets when the property name is calculated dynamically or is not a valid identifier (e.g. it contains special characters). But there's nothing prohibiting using it in other contexts. So `array['push']` is equivalent to `array.push`, and therefore `array['push'](5)` is equivalent to `array.push(5)`.

Answer (score 0):

`array['push']('5');` translates to:

```
const array = [];
array.push('5');
```

Since `push` is always a method on arrays, it can be accessed via association like `['push']` or directly as a property.

Comment: The OP did not show where `array` was declared (as `const`). So, the translation isn't necessarily exact.

Comment: `5` is not `'5'`

Comment: @UdoE. Its not supposed to be an exact translation. Its simply demonstrating the core concepts via code.